# A question about permutations inspired by a game

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

This question is inspired by a game I played.

Define an action $P_k$ on a finite sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^m (m>k)$: choose $k$ consecutive terms (from the sequence), move them to the middle of two terms (or append them at the beginning or end) of the remaining sequence to form a new sequence $\{a_n'\}_{n=1}^m$.

For example, if we apply $P_3$ to the sequence $1,3,7,5,6$, the result could be
\begin{align*}
1,3,\color{red}{7,5,6}&\xrightarrow{P_3}1,\color{red}{7,5,6},3\\
1,3,\color{red}{7,5,6}&\xrightarrow{P_3}\color{red}{7,5,6},1,3\\
1,\color{blue}{3,7,5},6&\xrightarrow{P_3}1,6,\color{blue}{3,7,5}\\
1,\color{blue}{3,7,5},6&\xrightarrow{P_3}\color{blue}{3,7,5},1,6\\
&\quad\vdots
\end{align*}

> **Question**
>
> **1.** Prove: any sequence formed by permutations of $1,2,3,4,5,6$ could be "reduced" to $1,2,3,4,5,6$ after applying $P_3$ for finite times.
>
> **2.** Find all $k$ such that any sequence formed by permutations of $1,2,3,\dots,2k$ could be "reduced" to $1,2,3,\dots,2k$ after applying $P_k$ for finite times.

---

For **Qn 1**, let $\mathcal B=\{(1\ 2),(2\ 3),(3\ 4),(4\ 5),(5\ 6)\}$, where all elements in $\mathcal B$ are [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). For example, $(1\ 2)$ means $\color{red}{a_4,a_6},a_5,a_2,a_1,a_3\to\color{red}{a_6,a_4},a_5,a_2,a_1,a_3$.

Apply $P_3$ several times, we could get $(1\ 2)$:
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
1\color{red}{234}56&\to &\color{red}{234}156&&&&&&\\
&=&234\color{blue}{156}&\to&2\color{blue}{156}34&&&&\\
&&&=&21\color{orange}{563}4&\to&214\color{orange}{563}&&\\
&&&&&=&21\color{green}{456}3&\to&213\color{green}{456}
\end{array}
\end{align*}
By symmetry, we could get $(5\ 6)$. We could also get $(2\ 3)$ and $(3\ 4)$ with some effort. Since all $6!=720$ permutaions could be generated by the composition of elements in $\mathcal B$ (e.g. $(1\ 3)=(2\ 3)(1\ 2)(2\ 3)$), we finished the proof.

For **Qn 2**, I tried to use the same approach, but failed. I think we might choose a different $\mathcal B$ such as $\mathcal B':=\{(1\ 2),(1\ 3),(1\ 4),\dots, (1\ 2k)\}$.

Are there any elegant ways to solve these questions?

Comment: Great question! What game is this inspired by? :)

Comment: When $k$ is even, this is impossible, because the parities of all reachable permutations are even.

Comment: @Shaun [3uttons](https://indienova.com/g/3uttons), a puzzle game with only 3 buttons.